# How to grep for quotation symbol (")

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have this code:

```
> head(row.names(django_c1))
[1] "10" "16" "25" "26" "28" "48"
> row.names(django_c1) <- gsub("\"", "", row.names(django_c1))
> head(row.names(django_c1))
[1] "10" "16" "25" "26" "28" "48"
```

What I am trying to do is to delete all the quotation marks ("), however, it doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried:

```
row.names(django_c1) <- as.numeric(row.names(django_c1))
```

and:

```
row.names(django_c1) <- gsub(""", "", row.names(django_c1))
```

But none of these seem to work either. How can I delete the quotation marks?

Comment: What exactly does it say when you do `as.numeric(row.names(django_c1))`?

Comment: These are not real quotes, just a print method of character strings. You could do either `str <- c("10", "16", "25", "26", "28" ,"48") ; noquote(str)` or `print(str, quote = FALSE)`

Comment: @blakeoft: they are displayed as numbers when I just run `as.numeric(row.names(django_c1))` but as soon as I impute it to the rownames using `row.names(django_c1) <- as.numeric(row.names(django_c1))` it's back to strings

Comment: @histelheim, they never stopped being strings, you can suppress the quotes when you print them with as.numeric or any of the options David mentionned but you can't prevent them from staying names for R. Why do you need to suppress the quotes ?

Comment: @histelheim Ah yes, I see. May I ask why you want to delete the quotes? As the others have stated, character vectors surround the elements in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You have this display because the result of `rownames` is a vector of character strings `typeof()=="character"`, so R displays `"` around it to show that fact.
If you do `head(django_c1)` you won't see them.

Row and colum names are always character strings, if you want to access by arbitrary index, either use a `list` (but you will probably create issues since `list[[2]]=0` automatically creates `list[[1]]=NA`) or use `django_c1[str(custom_index),]`.

Precision : `gsub('"', '', string)` will perfectly remove `"` from your string if they are *really* part of your string, which means 'hey"' (displayed "hey\"") becomes 'hey' (displayed "hey"). The distinction must be clear between the content of the string and the way it is displayed.

Comment: After you run your code, `row.names(django_c1)` is still a character vector.

Comment: `row.names(django_c1) = as.numeric(row.names(django_c1))` will not work. However, I can do `django_c1_rownames <- as.numeric(row.names(django_c1))` and utilize that variable instead

Comment: @blakeoft yep, typed this paragraph too fast, sorry. I corrected.

Comment: I can't get `gsub('"', '', string)` to work. See here: `> output <- row.names(django_c1)
> head(output)
[1] "10" "16" "25" "26" "28" "48"
> output <- gsub('"', '', output)
> head(output)
[1] "10" "16" "25" "26" "28" "48"`

Comment: `gsub('"', '', string)` only works if `string` actually contains a quote. For example, `string <- '"books"'; gsub('"', '', string)`. I don't think that the quotes in your row names are actually part of the strings. I think of the quotes as a way of easily seeing that the variable is a character.

Comment: What's `django_c1[str(custom_index),]`? Never saw such type of indexing

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just mean that if your `rownames` are for example `c("10", "50", "100")`, you can access column 2 by doing `django_c1[str(50),]`